# Add a shape which is created with PythonOcc to the IFC model using IfcOpenShell

Tags: python, ifc, ifc-open-shell

At the moment I have an issue with making an object visible in the IFC model. I created a shape, named `example_shape`, with PythonOCC [1].  This shape is visible in my 3D viewer of IfcOpenShell in the desired color [2]. Now I want this `example_shape` also to be visible in the new exported IFC model with a certain propertyset. I can not find any useful information about this topic.

```python
# [1]
example_shape = OCC.BRepAlgoAPI.BRepAlgoAPI_Common(extrusion_Surface, element_shape).Shape()

# [2]
fill = OCC.Quantity.Quantity_Color(r, g, b, OCC.Quantity.Quantity_TOC_RGB)
ifcopenshell.geom.utils.display_shape(example_shape, clr=fill)
```

I tried differents ways, but no good or desired output. Is there anyone here who had the same problem once before?